# How do I perform conditional operations to a list of strings, then return a new list?

Tags: python, for-loop, append, truncate

I'm writing a function that takes a list, and whenever a string is greater than `M`, it is truncated and   `"..."` is appended. This is what I've written so far.

```
# example input:
words = ['We', 'hold', 'these', 'truths', 'to', 'be', 'self-evident,', 'that', 'all', 'men', 'are', 'created', 'equal,', 'that', 'they', 'are', 'endowed', 'by', 'their', 'Creator', 'with', 'certain', 'unalienable', 'Rights,', 'that', 'among', 'these', 'are', 'Life,', 'Liberty', 'and', 'the', 'pursuit', 'of', 'Happiness.--That', 'to', 'secure', 'these', 'rights,', 'Governments', 'are', 'instituted', 'among', 'Men,', 'deriving', 'their', 'just', 'powers', 'from', 'the', 'consent', 'of', 'the', 'governed,', '--That', 'whenever', 'any', 'Form', 'of', 'Government', 'becomes', 'destructive', 'of', 'these', 'ends,', 'it', 'is', 'the', 'Right', 'of', 'the', 'People', 'to', 'alter', 'or', 'to', 'abolish', 'it,', 'and', 'to', 'institute', 'new', 'Government,', 'laying', 'its', 'foundation', 'on', 'such', 'principles', 'and', 'organizing', 'its', 'powers', 'in', 'such', 'form,', 'as', 'to', 'them', 'shall', 'seem', 'most', 'likely', 'to', 'effect', 'their', 'Safety', 'and', 'Happiness.', 'Prudence,', 'indeed,', 'will', 'dictate', 'that', 'Governments', 'long', 'established', 'should', 'not', 'be', 'changed', 'for', 'light', 'and', 'transient', 'causes;', 'and', 'accordingly', 'all', 'experience', 'hath', 'shewn,', 'that', 'mankind', 'are', 'more', 'disposed', 'to', 'suffer,', 'while', 'evils', 'are', 'sufferable,', 'than', 'to', 'right', 'themselves', 'by', 'abolishing', 'the', 'forms', 'to', 'which', 'they', 'are', 'accustomed.', 'But', 'when', 'a', 'long', 'train', 'of', 'abuses', 'and', 'usurpations,', 'pursuing', 'invariably', 'the', 'same', 'Object', 'evinces', 'a', 'design', 'to', 'reduce', 'them', 'under', 'absolute', 'Despotism,', 'it', 'is', 'their', 'right,', 'it', 'is', 'their', 'duty,', 'to', 'throw', 'off', 'such', 'Government,', 'and', 'to', 'provide', 'new', 'Guards', 'for', 'their', 'future', 'security.--Such', 'has', 'been', 'the', 'patient', 'sufferance', 'of', 'these', 'Colonies;', 'and', 'such', 'is', 'now', 'the', 'necessity', 'which', 'constrains', 'them', 'to', 'alter', 'their', 'former', 'Systems', 'of', 'Government.', 'The', 'history', 'of', 'the', 'present', 'King', 'of', 'Great', 'Britain', 'is', 'a', 'history', 'of', 'repeated', 'injuries', 'and', 'usurpations,', 'all', 'having', 'in', 'direct', 'object', 'the', 'establishment', 'of', 'an', 'absolute', 'Tyranny', 'over', 'these', 'States.']

M = 5 # desired character limit

count = 0 # setting up counter 

for str in words: # for any strings contained in the "words" list
  
  trunc = str[:M] + "..." # defines truncated string length, appends "..."

  if len(str) > M: # if word length is greater than M
    count += 1 # adds 1 to the counter each loop
    print(trunc) # prints truncated string

  elif len(str) <= M: # if word length is below or equal to M
    print(str) # prints original string

print("Truncated Words:", count) # prints final count
```

Right now, everything works and it prints each string one at a time.

Now I want to append each value to a new list and print the list instead, like this:

`['We', 'hold', 'these', 'truth...', 'to', 'be', 'self-...', 'that', 'all', 'men', 'are', 'creat...', 'equal...']`

but I'm not sure if `for str in words:` allows me to do this since the function doesn't know the difference between list[0] and list[1].

I tried adding
`list2 = []`
under `for str in words:` and
`return list2.append(str)` ,
`return list2.appent(trunc)`
to the end of each if statement, but `print(list2)` only returns `['State...']`, the last string in the list. How do I modify only some items in `words`, and return them to their correct space in the new list?

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?  It's not appropriate to ask us whether a particular coding sequence will do what you want: you have the ultimate authority right in front of you -- the Python interpreter.

Comment: I believe you have all the pieces you need in your answer, but what happens when you try what you've suggested?

Comment: It would only return the last string in the list. I assume that's because "str" is a placeholder for only the most recent value. So my question was on whether I could continue with "str in words:" or if my issue was with trying to append str & trunc from inside the function

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a list of all the truncated words, I suggest to:

1)
Set up an empty list to hold your modified words (the ones that stay the same + the truncated words). Place this at the start and outside of your **for** loop.

```
trunc_words=[]
```

2. 

Keep the for/if/elif loop as it is (I'm suggesting this so you can keep your code structure constant as this might help you follow the answer better).
Now you need to get the words that enter the if and the elif conditions to be appended to the new list (trunc_words list) by adding the following:

To the **if**, append the truncated word:

```
trunc_words.append(trunc)
```

To the **elif**, append the actual word that entered the for loop:

```
trunc_words.append(i)
```

Basically your whole code would look like this (have shortened your original word list though, and I'm using "i" instead of "str" as you shouldn't use a reserved word to define a variable/counter):

```
# example input:
words = ['We', 'hold', 'these', 'truths', 'to', 'be', 'self-evident,', 'that', 'all', 'men', 'are', 'created', 'equal,', 'that', 'they', 'are', 'endowed', 'by', 'their', 'Creator', 'with']
trunc_words=[]

M = 5 # desired character limit

count = 0 # setting up counter 

for i in words: # for any strings contained in the "words" list
  
  trunc = i[:M] + "..." # defines truncated string length, appends "..."

  if len(i) > M: # if word length is greater than M
    count += 1 # adds 1 to the counter each loop
    trunc_words.append(trunc)
    print(trunc) # prints truncated string

  elif len(i) <= M: # if word length is below or equal to M
    trunc_words.append(i)
    print(i) # prints original string

print(trunc_words)
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `for var in list` doesn't allow inplace modification. You can either use `enumerate` to modify list (but strings are immutable, so they'll be created again and old will be processed later with garbage collector)

```
for i, s in enumerate(words):
    words[i] = s[:min(len(s),M)] + ('...' if len(s)>M else '')
```

or create new list with list comprehension:

```
trunc_words = [s[:min(len(s),M)] + ('...' if len(s)>M else '') for s in words]
```

And please avoid using built-in names as variables. `str` is a type, and code, where `len(str)` is called, will always surprise reader.